# How to refresh div outside ng-view

Tags: angularjs, refresh

I have an AngularJS app and Node.js backend. My main layout-file looks something like this:

```
<div id="advert">
  <!-- DoubleClick javascript code -->
</div>
<div ng-view></div>
```

What I need, is to way to refresh the div with the DoubleClick code, which is outside the ng-view, every time the Angular route is changed, meaning, user navigates to new "page". At the moment, the ad is changing only when the page is refreshed from the browser, ie. when the user first arrives to the site.

I know it's possible, since it is described here http://davidlitwak.com/the-unseen-cost-of-using-the-best-technology-angularjs

But HOW, to do it, that is the question!

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize the `$routeChangeSuccess` event ([docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24route)). Make a directive for the "adver" div; the controller of this directive will listen for that event (`$scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function() {...})`) and take appropriate action (load the content and put it in the div).